# Mail sending with ASP.NET using AJAX Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an .aspx page using `System.Net.Mail` for sending E-Mail messages.
A `linkbutton` click event causes this sending process. As you know, I cant disable `LinkButton`'s PostBack event. It means, when user hits the link, mail sending process occurs, and page posts back. I need to avoid this post back process. So, I need to use `Ajax Update Panel`, but actually I'm not really good at ASP.NET. My question is, how can I use Ajax Update Panel to send mail without post back?
Here is my `LinkButton`'s Source:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <asp:LinkButton class="button" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" ID="bas"><img src="button.png" alt="" />Convert / Cevir</asp:LinkButton>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't quite get this - is your email sending code stored client-side? If not, then how is it ever going to fire without posting back to the server?

Comment: Just put the link button inside updatePanel. It will work as AJAX.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Codes work on Server Side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update panel like this. Moreover don't forget you create the `<asp:scriptmanager>` on the page.

```
<tr>
   <td>
<asp:updatepanel id="updatepnl1" runat="server">
  <contenttemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton class="button" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" ID="bas"><img  src="button.png" alt="" />Convert / Cevir</asp:LinkButton>
  </contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
   </td>
</tr>
```